# android license not working

Tags: android, manifest, android-lvl

I need a little help. To make this short. I installed the generic license check code but when i uploaded my app to the market its not allowing users to use my app. It's telling them they don't have permission can someone show me what i missed?

```
   package com.test.test;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.app.Dialog;
   import android.content.DialogInterface;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.manifestxml.chakra.AESObfuscator;
   import com.manifestxml.chakra.LicenseChecker;
   import com.manifestxml.chakra.LicenseCheckerCallback;
   import com.manifestxml.chakra.ServerManagedPolicy;



   public class splash extends Activity {
    private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
        public void allow() {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            // Should allow user access.
            startMainActivity();

        }

        public void applicationError(ApplicationErrorCode errorCode) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            // This is a polite way of saying the developer made a mistake
            // while setting up or calling the license checker library.
            // Please examine the error code and fix the error.
            toast("Error: " + errorCode.name());
            startMainActivity();

        }

        public void dontAllow() {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }

            // Should not allow access. In most cases, the app should assume
            // the user has access unless it encounters this. If it does,
            // the app should inform the user of their unlicensed ways
            // and then either shut down the app or limit the user to a
            // restricted set of features.
            // In this example, we show a dialog that takes the user to Market.
            showDialog(0);
        }
    }
    private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "my key... sorry you cant see it";

    private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] { salt numbers here };
    private LicenseChecker mChecker;

    // A handler on the UI thread.

    private LicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;

    private void doCheck() {

        mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Try to use more data here. ANDROID_ID is a single point of attack.
        String deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        // Library calls this when it's done.
        mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();
        // Construct the LicenseChecker with a policy.
        mChecker = new LicenseChecker(this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
                new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
                BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
        doCheck();

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // We have only one dialog.
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Application Not Licensed")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage(
                        "This app does not appear to be valid.     
   Please purchase it from  Android Market. If this is an error, please contact the    
developer for a correction.")
   .setPositiveButton("Purchase",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
       int which) {
   Intent marketIntent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,



   Uri.parse("http://market.android.com/details?id="
                                                + 

getPackageName()));
                                startActivity(marketIntent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Exit",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        }).create();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mChecker.onDestroy();
    }

    private void startMainActivity() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ToggleButtonMain.class));  //REPLACE     
   MainActivity.class WITH YOUR 


   APPS ORIGINAL LAUNCH ACTIVITY
        finish();
    }

    public void toast(String string) {
        Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

here is my manifest file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test.name"
      android:versionName="1.6" android:versionCode="9">


<application  android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".splash" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>     


        <activity android:name = ".ToggleButtonMain">

</activity>




        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:name=".TimerActivity"
>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="Preferences" android:name=".TimerPrefActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CATEGORY_PREFERENCE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


             <activity android:name = ".TabBarExample">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>


<activity android:name = "meditationmusic">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>


    <activity android:name=".FirstTab" />
    <activity android:name=".SecondTab" />
    <activity android:name=".thirdTab" />
    <activity android:name=".fourthTab" />
    <activity android:name=".fifthTab" />
    <activity android:name=".sixthTab" />
    <activity android:name=".seventhTab" />
    <activity android:name=".HowToOpen" />
    <activity android:name=".viztech" />
    <activity android:name=".viznotes" />
    <activity android:name=".cleanchakra" />
    <activity android:name=".breathing" />
    <activity android:name=".benefits" />




    <receiver android:name=".TimerReceiver" ></receiver>
</application>

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

can someone help?... what did i overlook....thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you recreated the bug yourself?

Comment: everything seemed fine before i uploaded.. i guess i can run the files again.. it wont hurt. But is there a problem with my codes and i am overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY matches what is on market.android.com/publish exactly (click on edit profile to get there)?

Comment: yes i got the public key from my developer profile account. I need to figure out why this is happening. any thoughts...does the code look clean?